# 'subscript(_:)' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int, use a String.Index instead in swift

Tags: swift, string

This is my code:

```
let textRange = UETextRange(charIndex: i, length: l - i)
for j in textRange.charIndex...getCharIndexAfterEndOfRange(range: textRange) {   
    if String(initialText[j - 1]) == "\n" { //error here
        hits += 1
        let hitIndex = attributeRange.index + (hits - 1)
        if hitIndex <= paragraphStyles.count {
            let charIndex = paragraphStyles[hitIndex].charIndex
        }
    }
}
```

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing elements of a `String` in Swift works slightly differently to most languages. Swift's `String` subscript expects a `String.Index` (not an `Int`), as shown in the documentation:

```
@inlinable public subscript(i: String.Index) -> Character { get }
```

What we want to do instead is get the `startIndex`, offset that by the integer index we want, and then get *that* index from the string. Fixed code:

```
let char = initialText[initialText.index(initialText.startIndex, offsetBy: j - 1)]

if char == "\n" {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Good answer thanks @George. Also well worth reading is the section on String Indices in The Swift Programming Language book at https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/stringsandcharacters/#String-Indices Explains why this approach is necessary. First character in example above would be initialText[initialText.startIndex]

Answer (score 4):

## 2022

```
extension String {
    public subscript(_ idx: Int) -> Character {
        self[self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: idx)]
    }
}
```

Now you able to use `"asdf"[4]` syntax like in other languages :)

```
print( "asdffdsa"[0] ) // a
print( "asdffdsa"[1] ) // s
print( "asdffdsa"[2] ) // d
```